# Drupal dsm destroy all js

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I have a problem that looks strange :
I have a website and i'm actually working on it, sometimes when I do a dsm of a big object all the javascript of the site disapear. I have some errors like this in the console :

```
$(....).dropdown is not a function
```

I'm trying to flush the cache but doesn't fix this.

What can I do ?

Comment: I think devel is not guilty , we need to have more information about where you are using dsm in code , and do you have aggregation js activated ?

Comment: I don't have aggregation activated, I try to make this dsm in a form in the backoffice of a drupal commerce product (sometimes the page freeze because the dsm is too big), and sometimes all the javascript disapear. But the thing really strange is that this happen only on my computer, when I have this problem if I check on another person computer everything works but not on mine. (even after flush the cache and in private navigation). But the problem disapear by itself after 10-15 minutes

Comment: It's not an application issue , just using issue. If you have to dump a lot of information or huge data , use lower level function like var_dump , because dsm store into session message datas and can take lot of ressources. Also you can use `kprint_r($data);` to dump like dsm without store it into session messages

Comment: Okay i'll test that, thanks

Comment: I just have again this problem, but with a kpr(), and I just see that it's not the css, but bootstrap who doesn't load. I have these errors : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
bootstrap.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED